# Google Doc API Single Login

Tags: google-drive-api

**Here is what I am trying to do:**
Create an application which can pull down a single predefined Google Document.

**Desired approach:**

1. Create an app which automatically logs into Google Drive with the document owners account.
2. Once logged in the latest version of the document will be downloaded and presented to the user through the app.
3. This approach means that App users can access the document without a Google account.

**What I don't want:**

1. I don't want users to have to login to Google Drive themselves. I want people to be able to access the document automatically through the app.
2. I don't want the document to be public.

**The problem I have hit:**

All login approaches I can find within the Google documentation require the user to login through their Google Accounts - OAuth style for example. I can't find anyway of just hard coding the login for the single account owner into the application.

**Other notes**
I am creating this as a web app in PHP.

Any help or different approach suggestions gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: I am researching this same scenario. I need to be able to have access to a single google drive account, which is used soley by the PHP application without need for user credentials, or acceptance of permission to access it. I would assume all credentials could be supplied through PHP from the server to satisfy Google's OAuth creds, however it doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: 6 years later ... I'm doing the exact same thing ... and hating every minute of it.